# Wrong column being sorted when JTable Header clicked

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, jtableheader

I have the following code for a `RowSorterListener`. The purpose of this is to sort a column without affecting any other columns.

```
import javax.swing.event.RowSorterListener;
import javax.swing.event.RowSorterEvent;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class UnrelateData implements RowSorterListener {
    JTable table;
    int columnSorted = -1;
    Object[][] dataStore;

    public UnrelateData(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getType() == RowSorterEvent.Type.SORT_ORDER_CHANGED) {
            List<SortKey> keys = e.getSource().getSortKeys();
            for (SortKey key : keys) {
                if (key.getColumn() == -1) {
                    columnSorted = -1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    columnSorted = key.getColumn();
                    break;
                }
            }
            dataStore = getData();
        }

        if(e.getType() == RowSorterEvent.Type.SORTED) {
            List<SortKey> keys = e.getSource().getSortKeys();
            for (SortKey key : keys) {
                if (key.getColumn() == -1) {
                    columnSorted = -1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    columnSorted = key.getColumn();
                    break;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                if(i != columnSorted && columnSorted != -1) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < table.getRowCount(); j++) {
                        table.setValueAt(dataStore[i][j], j, i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Object[][] getData() {
        int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
        int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
        Object[][] tempData = new Object[columnCount][rowCount];

        for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
                tempData[i][j] = table.getValueAt(j, i);
            }
        }

        return tempData;
    };
}
```

This works well. However, there is one major glitch. If a column is moved and I try to sort a column it doesn't correctly sort the column. Instead, it incorrectly sorts the column in the original place of the column moved.

[image: Column 2 and 3 switched]

Whereas it should look like (Where "Column 1" and "Column 2" remain unsorted)

[image: Column 2 and 3 switch properly]

Would someone be able to explain why this occurs and how to fix it?

*Note: I do not want to use `JTableHeader.reorderingAllowed(false)`*

**Edit**

I added the following for loops into my code and tried different variations but it didn't seem to work

**Attempt 1**

```
if(e.getType() == RowSorterEvent.Type.SORTED) {
    int[] actualColumn = new int[table.getColumnCount()];
    for(int i = 0; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++){
        actualColumn[i] = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(i);
    }

    int[] actualRow = new int[table.getRowCount()];
    for(int i = 0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
        actualRow[i] = table.convertRowIndexToModel(i);
    }

    List<SortKey> keys = e.getSource().getSortKeys();
    for (SortKey key : keys) {
        if (key.getColumn() == -1) {
            columnSorted = -1;
            break;
        } else {
            columnSorted = key.getColumn();
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        if(i != columnSorted && columnSorted != -1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < table.getRowCount(); j++) {
                table.setValueAt(dataStore[i][j], actualRow[j], actualColumn[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
private Object[][] getData() {
    int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
    int rowCount = table.getRowCount();

    int[] actualColumn = new int[columnCount];
    for(int i = 0; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++){
        actualColumn[i] = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(i);
    }

    int[] actualRow = new int[rowCount];
    for(int i = 0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
        actualRow[i] = table.convertRowIndexToModel(i);
    }

    Object[][] tempData = new Object[columnCount][rowCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
            tempData[i][j] = table.getValueAt(actualRow[j], actualColumn[i]);
        }
    }

    return tempData;
};
```

Attempt 3 was both attempt one and two put together

Comment: please whats `if (key.getColumn() == -1) {`, this value can be reached as exception from `RepaintManager` (some of `indexOfBoundsException` can do that)

Answer (score 4):

- code in `RowSorterListener` is designatet to returns the index correctly (from `RowSorterListener`s event)
- by default you never need to know ordering from `JTable`s view, all those events are `models events`,
- add `TableColumnModelListener` in the case that you want to trace `columnMoved`, all events from sorting programatically are painted in `JTable`s view correctly
- 1st. attemtp without column reordering,

[image]

```
Column NO. - 0 is sorted
Column NO. - 1 is sorted
Column NO. - 2 is sorted
Column NO. - 3 is sorted
Column NO. - 4 is sorted

... and so on
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)
```

.

- 2nd. attempt with column reordering (by mouse dragging)

[image]

.

```
Column NO. - 0 is sorted
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
Column NO. - 1 is sorted
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
Column NO. - 2 is sorted
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
columnMoved from ColumnModelListener
Column NO. - 3 is sorted
Column NO. - 4 is sorted
Column NO. - 0 is sorted
Column NO. - 1 is sorted
Column NO. - 2 is sorted
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

- 3rd. attempt the same correct output if Swing Timer isn't initialized and all event are made by users hand
- for example

.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SortTest1 {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(10, 5) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);
    private TableRowSorter<?> sorter;
    private static final Random rnd = new Random();
    private Timer timer;
    private int columnNo = 0;


    public SortTest1() {
        for (int row = model.getRowCount(); --row >= 0;) {
            int i = 20 + row % 20;
            model.setValueAt(row + " " + i, row, 0);
            model.setValueAt(i + row, row, 1);
            model.setValueAt(rnd.nextBoolean(), row, 2);
            model.setValueAt(rnd.nextDouble(), row, 3);
            model.setValueAt(row + " " + i * 1, row, 4);
        }
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        sorter = (TableRowSorter<?>) table.getRowSorter();
        sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
        sorter.addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {

            @Override
            public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent rse) {
                if (rse.getType() == RowSorterEvent.Type.SORT_ORDER_CHANGED) {
                    List<SortKey> keys = rse.getSource().getSortKeys();
                    for (SortKey key : keys) {
                        System.out.println("Column NO. - " + key.getColumn() + " is sorted");
                        if (key.getColumn() == 0) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {
            // just handle columnMarginChanged to re-paint headings
            @Override
            public void columnMarginChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                System.out.println("columnMarginChanged from ColumnModelListener");
            }

            @Override
            public void columnAdded(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                System.out.println("columnAdded from ColumnModelListener");
            }

            @Override
            public void columnRemoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                System.out.println("columnRemovedfrom ColumnModelListener");
            }

            @Override
            public void columnMoved(TableColumnModelEvent e) {
                System.out.println("columnMoved from ColumnModelListener");
            }

            @Override
            public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("columnSelectionChanged from ColumnModelListener");
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, updateCol());
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    private Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("Sort JTable") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (columnNo > 4) {
                    columnNo = 0;
                    sorter.setSortKeys(Arrays.asList(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnNo, SortOrder.ASCENDING)));              
                } else {
                    sorter.setSortKeys(Arrays.asList(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnNo, SortOrder.ASCENDING)));
                    columnNo++;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new SortTest1();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From your problem description (haven't looked at the code) you probably are not converting indexes reported from view indexes to model index or vice versa.

Cf [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) general description, to quote the relevant part:

> Similarly when using the sorting and filtering functionality provided by `RowSorter` the underlying `TableModel` does not need to know how to do sorting, rather `RowSorter` will handle it. Coordinate conversions will be necessary when using the row based methods of `JTable` with the underlying `TableModel`. All of `JTables` row based methods are in terms of the `RowSorter`, which is not necessarily the same as that of the underlying `TableModel`. For example, the selection is always in terms of `JTable` so that when using `RowSorter` you will need to convert using `convertRowIndexToView` or `convertRowIndexToModel`. [...]

You need to be aware that listeners on your table will report in view indexes, not model indexes. If you use a view index to get values from the model, you will experience the problem you are describing.

To handle these conversions, following methods exist in JTable:

- [convertRowIndexToModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)
- [convertRowIndexToView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView%28int%29)
- [convertColumnIndexToModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29)
- [convertColumnIndexToView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView%28int%29)

A small example to explain model vs view in a `JTable` in relation to your problem. The model of a table contains the data. The view is what is shown on the screen. The view maps its columns to columns in the model. When the column is dragged to a different position in the view (i.e. what you see on screen), your model is not changed (i.e. the data in the data container is not changed). What happens is that the mapping from view to model changes.

For example you have three columns A, B and C in your data model and you drag the second column on screen to the first position so that the order becomes B, A, C on screen. What the view does is change its mapping to show column B in the first position, A in the second position and C in the third position. So the mapping was `view:1->model:A, view:2->model:B, view:3->model:C` and after the dragging becomes `view:1->model:B, view:2->model:A, view:3->model:C`.

Now back to what I said before. When any listener on a `JTable` reports indexes (row, column) it does so with view indexes. Now if you want to look up what the value is at those indexes in the model, you first need to translate those view indexes to model indexes using the methods I highlighted before.

So you always need to be aware what indexes you are receiving and what you intend to do with them. If you receive indexes from the table (i.e. the view) and you want to use those to look up values in the model, you first need to translate the indexes using the `convertXXXToModel` methods.

Comment: Unfortunately this made no difference in the problem sorry

Comment: @Dan I saw your update, and you're using it wrong. Please check the documentation on these methods. They have a return value (the converted index) and you're not using the converted index. At least I'm not seeing that in the short code fragment you posted.

Comment: I glanced at your code. Whenever you index `dataStore` with indexes returned from your listener, you first need to convert the indexes to model indexes using the methods I highlighted in my answer.

Comment: I tried several attempts at including the new indexes but I am not sure where I am going wrong. Would you be able to advise (based on the edit)

Comment: Can you please first read the following: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting.