# JTable sorting not the good value in the cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using NetBeans to write a program. I create a JTable with the design and I add rows to the table without any problem.

When I click on the tab to sort the table it works, with `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`. However when I try to get the value of the updated cell it is not the good one. Indeed, it is the value of the previous cell, when I fill my table.

This is how I add row to my table:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
for (int i = 0; i < arrayPep.size(); i++) {
   model.addRow(new Object[]{arrayPep.get(i).getPeptide(), arrayPep.get(i).getStart(), arrayPep.get(i).getStop(), arrayPep.get(i).geteValue(), arrayPep.get(i).getName()});
}
```

This is how I try to get the value of the cell:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
table.getModel().getValueAt(rowSelected, 0);
```

How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

You are indexing the model with an index from the view. First convert the view index to a model index using [`JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(rowSelected)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)):

```
int modelRowSelected = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowSelected);
table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRowSelected, 0);
```

For some context regarding view indexes and model indexes, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830143/243373) I gave on the topic.